# C read and parse serial port

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino

I'm sending data from Arduino to serial port:

```
byte xBeeFrame[23];
unsigned int windData, 
signed int tempData;
xBeeFrame[0] = 0x7E;
xBeeFrame[18] = (windData >> 8) & 0xFF;
xBeeFrame[19] = windData & 0xFF;
xBeeFrame[20] = (tempData >> 8) & 0xFF;
xBeeFrame[21] = tempData & 0xFF;
```

The problem is to parse this data in C program. How cat I do it?
Here is how I'm reading serial port:

```
unsigned char bytes[254];
                if (read(tty_fd,bytes,sizeof(bytes))>0){
                    ///write(STDOUT_FILENO,bytes,sizeof(bytes));              // if new data is available on the serial port, print it out
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: I am curious, why is the structure you are using called xBeeFrame - you are just sending over a serial port, right?  Any reason it is not declared as a struct?  Also, why are bytes 1-17 empty?  And finally, why are you trying to read it into a 254-byte buffer?

Comment: The 1-17 are not empty. They are filled with another data. For example xBeeFrame[0] is 0x7E (delimiter). The problem is that I'm new to C and don't know how to read the data. Can you suggest please? What can I use for read buffer? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so what I would do first is create a separate header file to declare the structures you will use to communicate between the Arduino and the PC. So in a file like `comms.h`

```
#ifndef COMMS_H
#define COMMS_H
typedef struct commFrame_t commFrame_t {
    unsigned int wind, 
    signed int temperature;     
}
#endif COMMS_H
```

Then in your Arduino code you'll need to `#include "comms.h"` and then send the data as follows:

```
commFrame_t frame;
// Fill the frame with data
frame.wind = someWindValue;
frame.temperature = someTemperatureValue;
// Send the frame
Serial.write(&frame, sizeof(frame));
```

On the PC side you'll also `#include "comms.h"` and read the same frame:

```
commFrame_t frame;

if (read(tty_fd,&frame,sizeof(frame))){
    // Process a frame
}
```

This is not foolproof, as lost characters will cause the whole protocol to go out of whack, but might be OK as an initial prototype.  Unless you are passing the structure directly to some XBee device, I don't see why you need the delimiter for instance.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. The delimiter is used, because I have 4 arduino+xbee devices that are sending (every second) temp and wind data to one another xBee device which is connected to PC. So the data in serial port is comming in chaotic order.